# Build Disruptor in C++ gives error on autoconf

Tags: c++, disruptor-pattern

I downloaded the disruptor sources from here:

https://github.com/fsaintjacques/disruptor--

I then tried but get the given error. **Is there something that I am missing?**

```
autoconf configure.ac > configure

configure.ac:9: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:19: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_0X
```

gcc version

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

autoconf version

```
autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.63
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
```

Comment: I don't suppose [this would help](http://adesklets.sourceforge.net/forum_archive/topics/404.html)

Comment: disruptor---master idf$ autoheader  autoheader: error: AC_CONFIG_HEADERS not found in configure.ac

Comment: good resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603163/automake-error-ltmain-sh-not-found

Comment: I was able to build it this time. I have cmake 3.5.x and gcc 4.9.x

Answer (score 4):

Ask the developer to provide a `bootstrap` script and/or build instructions. Most likely you need:

```
aclocal
autoconf
automake -a
./configure
make
```

With possibly some non-default options (e.g. add `--foreign` to the automake invocation).

Comment: disruptor---master idf$ automake
configure.ac:9: error: required file './install-sh' not found
configure.ac:9:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'install-sh'
configure.ac:9: error: required file './missing' not found
configure.ac:9:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'missing'
perf/Makefile.am: error: required file './depcomp' not found
perf/Makefile.am:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'depcomp'
parallel-tests: error: required file './test-driver' not found

Comment: Yes, the error message is telling you, invoke automake with `--add-missing`, or `-a`.

Comment: Daniel thanks for your help. I was able to get far, but this whole disruptor thing on c++ anyway is very vague.